A geometric algebra to represent lines and circles
I recently came across this video on Projective Geometric Algebra A Swift Introduction to Projective Geometric Algebra. I was surprised by how powerful it was in finding intersection of lines, lines passing through two points, rotations etc. My question: can a Geometric Algebra be constructed which incorporates objects such as circles and has the above mentioned advantages of Projective Geometric Algebra. More specifically, can a Geometric Algebra be constructed which can:

easily represent points, lines AND circles
provide a simple way to find the intersection point of circles and circles, lines and circles, lines and lines
provide a simple way to construct a line through two points and a circle through three points
given two points, provide a simple way to construct the circle with one point as its center and another point on its circumference

If such a Geometric Algebra has already been constructed, please do tell me something about it in your answer as well as provide some sources where I can read up on it. In case such a Geometric Algebra doesn't exist, how can I construct one? Also, does there exist any formal textbook which covers how to use Geometric Algebra as a model of Euclidean Space and Geometry?

I believe you're looking for "Conformal Geometric Algebra" (CGA). You can find info an references on Wikipedia and other places that internet searches bring up, like this wiki for CGA.

both the Wikipedia page and the wiki page assume that you have knowledge of some prerequisites. For example, what is a dipole, flat point and round point? Could you share an article/book which covers CGA from the ground up?
